# Custom embed command not working discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I tried to write custom embed command, but something gone wrong, this is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx, tit, desc, col):
  col2 = discord.Color. + col + ()
  embed = discord.Embed(name=tit, description=desc, colour=col2)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

And the error is this: invalid syntax.
Can anyone help me please?
PS. I'm new here, so if I wrote something wrong or didn't write something, I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot operate on those objects like on strings, if you have a string, i.e `red`, and want to get the `discord.Colour.red()` method, you can use `getattr`

```py
color = "red"  # hardcoded for explanation purposes
actual_color = getattr(discord.Colour, color)()
```

Keep in mind that this will throw an error if the `color` variable is invalid (if the `discord.Colour` class doesn't have an attribute/method like that), you can add a simple if-statement to check if it's valid:

```py
color = "red"  # hardcoded for explanation purposes
actual_color = getattr(discord.Colour, color)
if actual_color is not None:
    actual_color = actual_color() 
    ...  # valid color
else:
    # invalid color
```